# Can you ever omit haber?

Tags: coloquialismos, letras-de-canciones, haber

In the song Toy Story, there’s a line “Ya te dejado de seguir, pero miro tus stories.”

According to Google, this means “I have stopped following you, …”

Why is haber not used here for the “have”? Is there a rule for when it can be omitted like the above?

Comment: I clearly heard [Ya te he dejado de seguir](https://www.letras.com/lola-indigo/toy-story/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be based on a mis-hearing of the words and so is not really about the Spanish language itself.

Comment: https://www.thoughtco.com/apocopation-of-adjectives-3079086

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the fact that the OP has not heard the song well or is confused with the lyrics, the question has an answer: the verb *haber* can never be removed from a past perfect continuous since it's part of the verbal form.

---

A different issue is that there's an oral contraction between words and monosyllables that end and begin with the same vowel, with or without an intermediate mute *h*. Contractions don't exist in Spanish as in English or French, however, they are very common in oral and written Spanish, especially in chats, songs, SMS, online texting, etc. The two recognized forms of contractions in Spanish are "al" (for "a el") and "del" (for "de el"). But colloquial language admits contractions such as "palante" and "patrás" (for "para adelante" and "para atrás").

There are many examples. The Ricky Martin song, *Vente pa' ca*, in correct Spanish would be *Vente para acá*, where the syllable *ra* disappears both in the title and in the lyrics.

The clarification made by the RAE on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1052550181802188801?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) is:

> #RAEconsultas Siempre es preferible que una de las dos palabras esté completa: «p'alante». Con ello se favorece el reconocimiento de toda la secuencia.

<sub>*More about Spanish contractions [here](https://www.twinkl.es/teaching-wiki/contracciones-en-espanol)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Creo que hay un desconocimiento o confusión en la interpretación /// I think there is a lack of knowledge or confusion in the interpretation;;

**Ya te dejó de seguir... / Te he dejado de seguir...**

---

**Toy Story** - Lola Indigo

> Que si tú no te quedas, me sabe a poco yo quiero comerte, no comerme
> el coco creo que va a explotar, es un terremoto no paro de fumar y no
> me coloco
>
> **Ya te he dejado de seguir** pero miro tus stories y es que yo solo
> pienso en ti aunque ya tengo otro shorty

---

La letra dice claramente "**Ya te he dejado de seguir**" .

The lyric says clearly "**Ya te he dejado de seguir**".

- La respuesta es no, no se puede omitir el verbo "haber".
- The answer is no, the verb "haber" cannot be omitted.

---

Diferencia entre "**ya te dejó de seguir" - "ya te he dejado de seguir**". Difference between "**ya te dejó de seguir" - "ya te he dejado de seguir**"

- "**Ya te dejó de seguir**" -  Se refiere a la tercera persona del pretérito perfecto simple o pretérito indefinido del verbo "dejar". (El) ya **te dejó** de seguir...

Its the third person of the past perfect simple or past indefinite of the verb "dejar". (El) ya **te dejó** de seguir...

- "**Te he dejado de seguir**" - Se refiere a la primera persona del pretérito perfecto del verbo "dejar". (Yo) **"te he dejado"** de seguir...

It is the first person of the past perfect of the verb "dejar". (Yo) **"te he dejado"** de seguir... (Yo he dejado de seguir - te (a ti)).